# Get changes done by a script

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-delete, spool

I need to write a script in order to delete specific records in the database that need to be re-entered for the user because they are corrupted.

The script is very simple. I first need to identify the records to be deleted and their dependencies and delete them all.

I tested my script in my dev environment and it worked well. My concern is when this script will be deployed into production it will delete the records that need to be deleted but I'd like to produce some kind of report of the deleted records to provide it to the client.

**How to generate a report of deleted rows ?**

What would be the best way to produce this report? Should I execute a spool? Is there a good practice or there are some tips you could give me ?

Thanks in advance!

Mario.

Comment: how many table ? do you just want a dry run "this'll be delete" or a log "this was deleted" ?

Comment: It's one parent table and 10 children tables.
It should be a dry run.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add your script ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to go with a combo `CREATE AS SELECT` and [`MINUS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) operator.

- 1st, you create temporary table with `CREATE TABLE t_dry AS (SELECT * FROM t)`
- 2nd, you run your script again `*_dry` tables,
- last, you make a `minus` between your source and dry.

Eg:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78553/26)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("a" int, "b" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t ("a", "b")
         VALUES (1, 2)
    INTO t ("a", "b")
         VALUES (3, 4)
    INTO t ("a", "b")
         VALUES (5, 6)
SELECT * FROM dual
;


CREATE TABLE t_dry
  AS (SELECT * FROM t);
;

update t_dry set "b" = 7 where "a" = 5;
delete from t_dry where "a" =3;

INSERT INTO t_dry ("a", "b")
         VALUES (8, 9)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (
  (
    SELECT '+' AS "Diff", T_DRY.* FROM T_DRY
    MINUS
    SELECT '+' AS "Diff", T.* FROM T
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT '-' AS "Diff", T.* FROM T
    MINUS
    SELECT '-' AS "Diff", T_DRY.* FROM T_DRY
  )
) A
ORDER BY A."a" , "Diff" DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78553/26/0)**:

```
| Diff | a | b |
|------|---|---|
|    - | 3 | 4 |
|    - | 5 | 6 |
|    + | 5 | 7 |
|    + | 8 | 9 |
```